# Sent email arrives with few hours delay

Tags: php, email

This is my email sending code:

```
if(isset($_POST['contactname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
  $contactname = $_POST['contactname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $subject = "Ձեզ գրել են ձեր կայքից";
  $to = "stereoshoots@gmail.com";
  $headers = "From: ".$email;
  mail($to,$subject,"Ձեզ գրել է: $contactname \n $message",$headers);
  echo "E-mail-ը հաջողությամբ ուղարկվեց";
}
else if(empty($_POST['contactname']) && empty($_POST['email']) && empty($_POST['message'])) {
  "erroooor";
}
```

Everything is ok there, everything works without any errors, but the email is coming after few hours. How can I fix this?

Comment: when is it arriving vice when you sent it?

Comment: This could be a problem of the mailserver it self. Generally saying, the php mail function sucks.

Comment: Can you post the headers for the mail message?  Also, this might be more on-topic at serverfault.

Comment: Your mail is especially heavy.

Comment: You do ask constantly but never accept, when people give you answers

Comment: I dont have other headers. Why is it heavy? Any solution?

Comment: @Marker Xeoncross was either guessing or trolling.

Comment: I'll do it this time, for sure.

Comment: Also I see your despair at the error message.

Comment: Yeah lol. No thats not a despair, i'll do an error thing after i solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the email is sent but it takes hours to reach someone's inbox, the problem is with the mail server, not with your app.

Comment: Email servers add a `Received` field to the email headers. Just have a look at the headers of a received email. Maybe you can figure out which server causes the delay.

Answer (score 1):

1.View the `"Email Header."`

2.Review the `"Received By"` email server to determine the location/I.P. address causing the email delay.

The delay is not because of code.